# Meteor {{#each in}} not scoping down correctly

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to use the feature {{#each test in calculation}} in a template, but am getting an error saying "No such function: test".  Here is a link to my code and I was hoping someone could show me where my mistake would be.

https://gist.github.com/claytonzaugg/c4191111159be68106f4

Thank you!
Clayton

Comment: You need to create a template *helper* that returns *test* as a cursor or array. *in calculation* is spurious.

Comment: How would I go about returning an array?  I ultimately want to do that, I agree with you, but how?  I currently have as my helper return Calculations.find(); but is there something else I need to add to the syntax to make it an array?

Comment: ANSWERED - my problem was that I was expecting to visually see something different, but in actuality, I was getting rows of all the test numbers I entered.  The problem was that I need to display the data differently instead of in rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change your template helper to:

```
Template.ListCalculations.helpers({
    test: function() {
        return Calculations.find();
    }
});
```

Or your html `{{#each}}` to:

```
{{#each calculations}} 
    <tr>
        <td>{{test.testNumber}}</td>
        <td>{{test.testName}}</td>
        <td>{{test.inputOne}}</td>
        <td>{{test.inputTwo}}</td>
        <td>{{test.inputThree}}</td>
        <td>{{#linkTo route="editCalculation"}}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>{{/linkTo}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

As @Michael Floyd mentioned, the `in calculations` is spurious.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the helpers to the following

```
Template.ListCalculations.helpers({
'test': function() {
    return Calculations.find();
}
```

});

and the template binding to this in the `each loop`

```
{{#each test}} 
            <tr>
                <td>{{testNumber}}</td>
                <td>{{testName}}</td>
                <td>{{inputOne}}</td>
                <td>{{inputTwo}}</td>
                <td>{{inputThree}}</td>
                <td>{{#linkTo route="editCalculation"}}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>{{/linkTo}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
```